# Correctly input int[] in java method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, input

This method insert takes as input `int[] array`, `int element`, and `int index`, which inserts `element` into the `index` position of `array`. Since an array is not resizable, the method shifts every element over to the right of the array by one. The element at the end is removed from the array. The method returns `void`.

```
public class ShiftElements {
public static void insert(int[] array, int element, int index)
{
    for (int i = array.length-1; i > index; i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1];
    }
    array[index] = element;
    }
}
```

To test if this method works, I changed the return type to `int[]` and wrote a main method to print `array`:

```
public class ShiftElements {
public static int[] insert(int[] array, int element, int index)
{
    for (int i = array.length-1; i > index; i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1];
    }
    return array;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(insert(4,5,3));
    }
}
```

I am having problems, getting this print statement to work. It's probably something simple, but I've been up for two days studying for finals so I'm pretty braindead.

I'm pretty sure I called the `insert` method just fine, but I think my issue is that I'm not properly inputting the type `int[]`. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do this.

Comment: What are you seeing printed, and what do you expect to see? I think that you'll want to look into using the `toString(...)` method of the java.util.Arrays class. As a rule of thumb when asking questions here, you'll want to give as much pertinent information as possible so that we can understand your problem well and better be able to answer it.

Comment: I just want to see the final values of the elements in the array to test if my insert method is working properly.

Comment: Since you are interested in testing your Java programs, you should learn and use the JUnit test framework.  In order for that to work well, you should also avoid writing static methods as they are harder to test.  Make the `insert` method non-`static`, and create a `ShiftElements` object in your main method, and call `insert` on it.

Comment: Why are you passing `4` as first argument in `insert` method while calling it within `main` ?

Comment: Vishal - I wanted the array to have 4 elements. I'm not sure if passing 4 is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you are looking for is :

```
int[] i = new int[5];
System.out.print(java.util.Arrays.toString(insert(i,5,3)));
```

Apart from the use of `java.util.Arrays.toString` method Watch out the parameters that you are passing in `insert` method:
first parameter should be an array of `int`. But you are passing an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

1) The first parameter of insert is an array of int, not an int. You must call :

```
insert(new int[]{4},5,3)
```

2) you can't print an array : so use :

```
println(Arrays.toString(insert(...)))
```

Comment: isn't passing `new int[]{4}` the same thing as passing `new int[4]` ? Just wondering about syntax. (still pretty much a noob in java)

Comment: new int[] {4} creates an array with one element : 4 (array.length == 1). new int[4] creates an array with 4 elements (array.length == 4). These 4 elements aren't initialized so they have their default value : 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.print(insert(4,5,3));
```

That statement does not pass a array of integers, you only passed and integer 4. You would need to pass, as your function is defined, int[], int, int.

```
System.out.print(insert(new int[4],5,3));
```

Comment: Thanks, this was one of the main problems I couldn't figure out!

Answer (score 1):

You made a call to `insert(int,int,int)` eventhough your signature for insert is `insert(int[],int,int)`. For instance, calling insert with an array literal would be like so:

```
insert(new int[]{1,2,4,5}, 3, 2);
```

Additionally, [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) is a much faster and elegant way to copy arrays. You also seem to have forgotten to set the element at its index within your second example:

```
public static int[] insert(int[] array, int element, int index)
{
    // Use arraycopy to shift all the elements by one, running over the last index
    System.arraycopy(array, index, array, index+1, array.length-index-1);

    // Set the appropriate index in the array to the specified value
    array[index]=element;

    return array;
}
```

If you then run the following, you will get your expected output:

```
int[] array =  {1, 2, 4, 5};
insert(array,3,2); // array is now {1,2,3,4}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to print the array then the most laymen procedure is to return the particular array and loop throw it to print its element. eg:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int []solution= insert(new int[4],5,3);
    for(int i=0;i<solution.length;i++)
    {
     System.out.println(solution[i]);
    }

}
```